# Extract data from an array in Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I need to extract the data from that map, I am getting some strange problems I am using the following code

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('busquedas').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }

      DocumentSnapshot _list =
          Busquedas.fromMap(snapshot.data.documents) as DocumentSnapshot;
      print(_list);

      return Container(
        child: Text(_list.toString()),
      );
    });
```

And in my models I am using the following code, The idea is to obtain the data in real time, and be able to update it in the future. I leave some photo of the error that throws me

[image]

```
class Busquedas {
    List<Parametro> parametros;
    Busquedas({
        this.parametros,
    });

  

    factory Busquedas.fromJson(String str) => Busquedas.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Busquedas.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Busquedas(
        parametros: List<Parametro>.from(json["parametros"].map((x) => Parametro.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "parametros": List<dynamic>.from(parametros.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

class Parametro {
    Parametro({
        this.oficio,
        this.fecha,
    });

    String oficio;
    String fecha;

    factory Parametro.fromJson(String str) => Parametro.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Parametro.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Parametro(
        oficio: json["oficio"],
        fecha: json["fecha"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "oficio": oficio,
        "fecha": fecha,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `snapshot.data` is `null`, which is why the error says `documents` was *called  on `null`*.

You're not checking if the snapshot actually has the data you want yet. Just add this check and `return` something to show while it's not available.

This example uses the same progress indicator you're currently using for errors for when data is not available. This can of course be modified by adding a separate `if` block.

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('busquedas').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {//Adding condition to return progress indicator if data isn't available
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }

      DocumentSnapshot _list =
          Busquedas.fromMap(snapshot.data.documents) as DocumentSnapshot;
      print(_list);

      return Container(
        child: Text(_list.toString()),
      );
    });
```

The purpose of this `builder` and the `snapshot` is so that *you* can control exactly what is shown based on the progress of your async function.